# EditTextPreference

Tags: android

Sorry for maybe a stupid question.

I have EditTextPreference... How to check is his text empty or not ?

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreference,
        String key) {
    String editorText= (editTextPreference.getText()).trim();
    if (editorText== "") {
        editorText.setText("Something");
    }
}
```

That's not work....

Comment: I should use equals...but not == ..sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also check for null.

try it:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextPreference.getText())) {
    editorText.setText("Something");}
```